# Can't read any electricity on recessed light

Tags: electrical, light

I just removed two lights and when I switch them on, I can't read any volts DC or AC. The wires have a cloth sheathe. I tested with both a contact sensor and with a multimeter. I thought they may be low voltage or DC, but I tested all that. There are two lights in the ceiling and I tested them both, including touching them after checking that they had no voltage.

I would appreciate any troubleshooting ideas.

Receptacle

[image]

Existing light

[image]

Writing on the side of the fixture

[image]

Light Outlet in Ceiling

[image]

Comment: Looks like there might be a photo missing ("Documentation"). Could you specify exactly how you checked for electricity? What tester, where did you put the leads/probe, what was connected/disconnected/switched on/off? Most importantly - what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hello. I used the Klein Tools Non Contact Voltage Tester Pen, 50 to 1000V AC tester and my multimeter between both wires (AC/DC amps volts). After testing for zero volts, I touched both wires with the switch on. There really isn't any voltage there. The word "documentation" was just to show the writing on the side of the fixture. My specific question is: what should I do to connect a regular 110V light switch there?

Comment: And why am I not seeing any volts? What type of light fixture is this?

Comment: The wire shown in the pictures and the label ("12v") both indicate that the wiring is vastly undersized to accept 110v (actually in the US and Canada: 120v) service. You cannot connect any "regular" mains current switch or fixture using this wiring.

Comment: You write that your voltage tester reads between 50-1000V, so it wouldn't detect 12V such as shown on your light fixture. Does the original light work? Have you looked at the switch area?

Comment: Where is your 12 volt transformer

Comment: @Ruskes -- I need to find that -- so I'm pretty sure it's above the cans. The multimeter should be able to detect the 12V.

Comment: It should detect, if the transformer is working. Find it